# Unable to redirect default Login page from Azure AD instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We are using ASPX project and need to change custom login to Azure AD login page.

Startup

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
              new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
              {
                  // `Authority` represents the identity platform endpoint - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0.
                  // `Scope` describes the initial permissions that your app will need.
                  //  See https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-scopes/.
                  ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
                  Authority = Globals.Authority,
                  //String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globals.Authority, "common", "/v2.0"),
                  RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                  Scope = "openid profile",
                  PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
              });
```

And did below changes in aspx page, to redirect

```
 if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
```

But it's not redirecting to login page, help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Please provide the web.config file.

Comment: After that Challenge call, are you ending the request or letting it continue to execute? You need to stop processing so the redirect doesn't get overwritten.